# Mac doesnt recognize Pixel 3A in fastboot mode

Tags: android, macos, fastboot

I have a Pixel 3A device in which I need to unlock the bootloader mode.
I have Mac with Big Sur.

Steps followed:

1. Connect Pixel via the type-c cable.
2. Enable USB debugging & OEM unlocking toggle.
3. Installed latest adb/fastboot tool and Android File Transfer Tool.
4. Run adb devices

   - device is shown with its serial number
5. Android File transfer tool detects the device, and shows its contents.
6. Run adb reboot bootloader

   - device goes into "fastboot" mode, as visible on its screen.
   - Run fastboot devices gives no result
   - Run adb devices gives no result.

I have also tried manually putting device into fastboot mode using the combination of volume up key & the power button, but the device is still not shown.

Is there a way for MAC to detect device in fastboot mode?
Is there any other way to unlock OEM?

Please anyone/any help is appreciated, kind of stuck in a desperate situation.
Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?